# How to install terality on google colabrotary

Tags: pandas, google-colaboratory

I want to install terality on google colab how to do that

i tried this first i wrote:

```
pip install --upgrade terality
terality account configure --email myemail@gmail.com
```

but after the next command it shows this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-5-01d28d6ffdce>", line 1
    terality account configure --email myemail17@gmail.com

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i even tried this:

```
pip install terality
```

and then i directly tried to use terality but it says the terlity client is not installed.

i want to use terality as it is faster so pls help:)

Answer (score 0):

These snippets are not Python code, but shell commands. In Google Colab, as well as in most Jupyter notebooks, a cell runs Python code by default.

To run a shell command in a cell, prefix the commands with a `!`:

```
!pip install terality
```

```
!terality account configure  --email myemail17@gmail.com
```

Also, this `terality` command is interactive (it reads further input from stdin), which likely won't work in a Jupyter notebook. You can use the non-interactive form instead:

```
!terality account configure  --email myemail17@gmail.com --api-key <apikey> --overwrite
```

(this non-interactive version is otherwise discouraged, as it stores your API key in the notebook itself).